# Carousel slide bootstrap 3 feature will not slide until after first iteration of the slide?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

> The bootstrap 3 carousel works perfectly fine, but only after a full 
>   iteration of all three images. So when I click through the images
>   for the first time there is no slide effect, but after I have seen all
>   the images once the next time I see them the slide effect will work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>My AngularJS App</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="//bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">

    <div class="container-fluid">

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/view1">Tommy Clark</a>

        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

        <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                <li class="active"><a href="#/view2">Home</a></li>

                <li class="dropdown">

                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Listings <b class="caret"> </b> </a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                        <li><a href="#">New Orleans</a></li>

                        <li><a href="#">Baton Rouge</a></li>

                        <li><a href="#">Monroe</a></li>

                    </ul>

                </li>

                <li class="menu-Aboutus"><a href="#/view4">About us</a></li>

                <li class="menu-Contact"><a href="#/view5">Contact</a></li>

            </ul>

        </nav>

    </div>

</header>

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner">

        <div class="item active">
            <img src="img/highResArch.jpg" alt="Arch" class="img-responsive">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Arch</h3>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="img/highResMidEast.jpg" alt="Hut" class="img-responsive">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>House in the sand</h3>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="img/highResOceanBridge.jpg" alt="Ocean" class="img-responsive">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Ocean Bridge</h3>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="icon-prev"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="icon-next"></span>
    </a>

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>﻿

<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="components/version/version.js"></script>
<script src="components/version/version-directive.js"></script>
<script src="components/version/interpolate-filter.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: looking fine there is nothing wrong. How about u click on
inspect element > console tab .

Comment: When going to the console I can see nothing that has not loaded. Everything works how its supposed to but only after the first iteration through all the images which just doesn't make sense. I just actually realized that this problem only occurs on chrome. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: is your website live?

Answer (score 0):

Remove this from the bottom of your page:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

And put this in the `<head>` section of your page instead.